# Installing wine on UBUNTU16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine

Installing wine to run Keil on UBUNTU.
it is giving following error while configuration.

```
winecfg
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/balmukund/.wine'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x103e368, overlapped 0x103e380): stub
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10fe8a0, overlapped 0x10fe8ac): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/balmukund/.wine' has been updated.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error **SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated** you need to install winbind:
Type the following as **root** user

```
# apt-get install winbind
```